# How to generate ID for entity from the existing ORACLE sequence?

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, sequence, jpql

I have a Table (for a long time ago), call it **TABLE_A**, and I have an **entity** class for this Table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_A")
public class TableA implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    //what else should I write here, to get the value from the existing sequence (seq_table_a_id) from database?
    private Long id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "VALID_TO_DT")
    private String name;

    getters/setters...
}
```

I had created a **sequence** for this table in **ORACLE** a long time ago, and I want to give values for the new item's *ID from this sequence*. How should I write this code in java entity with **annotations**? If you could write an example for my code, that would be helpful!

And should I write anything else maybe in the **persistance.xml**?

The name of the existing sequence is: `seq_table_a_id`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should check the annotation `@GeneratedValue` and `@SequenceGenerator`

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="seqGen")
@SequenceGenerator(name="seqGen",sequenceName="seq_table_a_id", allocationSize=1)
private Long id;
```

[Check this link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/id-generation-083058.html#sequence)